# How to listen for widget selection in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I'm adding custom widget via CKEDITOR.instances[editorId].insertHtml() (inside angular app),
and I need to react to widget selection, possibly deselection.

I see that widget fires events such as select, deselect, focus and blur but I can't find out how to set listeners on each widget.

Could this be done inside of plugin's init function?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either listen to this directly or indirectly.

The direct listener will need to use the [`widget.repository#instanceCreated`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-event-instanceCreated) event to be able to listen on [`widget#blur`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-event-blur) event on all created widgets:

```
editor.widgets.on( 'instanceCreated', function( evt ) {
    var widget = evt.data;

    // You can check at this point whether you want to observe this kind of widget
    // e.g. check widget.name.

    widget.on( 'blur', function() {
        // Fired when widget is deselected.
    } );
} );
```

The indirect method will use the [`editor#selectionChange`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-selectionChange) event to observe selection changes and [`widget.repository.focused`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-property-focused) property to check which widget is now selected (or not):

```
var lastFocused = null;

editor.on( 'selectionChange', function() {
    if ( lastFocused && lastFocused !== editor.widgets.focused ) {
        // The lastFocused widget just lost focus.
    } 

    lastFocused = editor.widgets.focused;
} );
```

Both methods are ok for most cases. First may consume slightly more memory if you expect bazillion of widgets :D.

BTW. Widget can be both [focused](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-property-focused) and [selected](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-property-selected). The difference is that multiple widgets can be selected at one time, while only one can be focused (then it has that blue outline). In most cases you'll be interested in the focused widget.